# Machine Learning - Feature Generation using dataframes with different sizes

Tags: pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-extraction

I have multiple CSV files with 18 columns of sensordata of a production cycle ordered by time. Each CSV file represents one product (smartphone), which production was either sucessful (1) or unsucessful (0). I converted each CSV to a dataframe and brought them together in a dictionary. The CSV files have different numbers of rows.

My question is now, if I do have to compress them into one single row with the result of either 1 or 0 at the end to compare different machine learning algorithm (like the multiple logistic regression). For my algorithm, each input is a dataframe, and the output is a label. Concatenating all the rows side by side into one single row could create feature vectors of different lengths.

For example: I have 7 CSV files converted into 7 dataframes and put them together in one dataframe with 7 rows (a single row for every dataframe).

If I have to compresss one DataFrame to a single row, could you tell me how to do so?

Or is it possible to tell the algorithm, that it has to consider every row of a whole dataframe (30000 rows).

Thank you very much!

Comment: What do you mean by "compress"..?

Comment: Like I tried to explain in the Example. (Sorry for my bad english but im german). Like putting a whole DataFrame with thousands of rows in a single row of another DataFrame.

Comment: It's okay, it's just that "compression" can be understood in many different ways when it comes to pandas. Can we see a sample of what you are looking for?

Comment: In this case its a theoretical question because I want to know how this works in general. How can I run a machine learning algorithm on multiple datasets. As far as I know the logisticRegression takes one row at the time. But In my case "one row" should be one dataset. Otherwise the sensordata become messy.

Comment: I think I see what you mean. The input is the dataframe and the output is a label (1 being successful and 0 otherwise). You want to use the ENTIRE dataframe as a feature to run a machine learning algorithm.That's tough. Does every dataframe have the same number of rows?

Comment: Yeah thats exactly what I meant! But they dont have the same number of rows. Does this matter?

Comment: Yes. For example you have 300 rows in one dataframe and 100 in another. Compressing the rows into one feature vector produces 5,400 features for the first dataframe and 1,800 features for the other. Machine learning models take inputs with identical dimensions. I'm going to edit your question to direct it to the right audience. See this also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28819104/how-to-do-machine-learning-when-the-inputs-are-of-different-sizes

Comment: Okay, thanks alot for your help!